# Cannot get Jquery Ketchup Plugin Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get te ketchup jquery plugin to work.  I know i must be missing something simple.  Someone please help!  nothing happens in the following html, no errors thrown..so i'm lost!  I tried to follow the simple steps here:  http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Yammie</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery.ketchup.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ketchup.all.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#default-behavior').ketchup();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="default-behavior" action="test.html">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="db-mail">E-Mail</label>
                    <input type="text" id="db-mail" data-validate="validate(required, email)" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="db-username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="db-username" data-validate="validate(required, username, minlength(3))" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="db-skill">Skills</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="db-skill" name="db-skill" data-validate="validate(minselect(2))" /> jQuery
                    <input type="checkbox" name="db-skill" /> HTML
                    <input type="checkbox" name="db-skill" /> CSS
                    <input type="checkbox" name="db-skill" /> Rails
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Is Tasty?" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try adding mustard ... if that doesn't work, throw in some mayo too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried now. It works for me. Try downloading **ketchup 0.3.2** from github: https://github.com/mustardamus/ketchup-plugin/downloads
Link all of this three js files: **ketchup.js**, **ketchup.validations.js** and **ketchup.helpers.js**

Comment: Thanks Joe, finally got it to work.  Guess i had the wrong version?  Frustating, but atleast now i know.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this scriot at the header & the form id must be default-behavior

```
            <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
                $(window).load(function(){
                               $('#default-behavior').ketchup();
                               });//]]>
                </script>
```